# How to save props or state values without using Redux

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-props

So, I'm still a beginner with React and I'm trying to save state value of "quantity"

```
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          visible: false,
          selected: false,
          quantity: ""
        }
        this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
    }
```

I want to pass this data to the component linked to the parent of this component and prevent losing data if I go back.

```
<Link to={`/itemSelection/${sessionStorage.getItem("")}/checkout`}>PROCEED</Link>
```

______________________________________________________-

EDITED

So the parent component is ItemSelection inside of it I import Item component and map through some data I get from api.

```
                <div className="row">
                    {this.state.items.map(i => <Item name={i.name} quantity={i.quantity} />)}
                </div>
```

the quantity I pass to Item is the whole quantity I get from the api.

Inside of Item component

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          visible: false,
          selected: false,
          quantity: ""
        }
        this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
    }
```

the quantity here is the quantity I select for every item I choose. when I click the link to the checkout component I lose this data and if I go back to the itemSelection component I find these data lost also. So I want to pass this quantity of every item to the checkout component and prevent losing the data if I go back again to the itemSelection component.
Hope this clarification make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You have to lift your state above the routing. IE:

```js
// ParentComponent hold state and pass it as props in RENDER props to route A and route B
<ParentComponent>
  <Switch>
    <Route ... render={props => <MycomponentA quantity={this.props.quantity}} />} /> // Route A
    <Route ...  render={props => <MycomponentA quantity={this.props.quantity}}/> // Route B
  </Switch>
</ParentComponent>
```

Comment: With complete structure is difficullt to see how much you have to lift your state. 
In your code I see a <Link /> so I suppose you are using react-router (v4 ?). You have to take advantage of the component's state CONTAINING the router and routes. When a component is remounted its state get resetted too so you have to place your state at a level that is not affected by a route change.
Keep going in this direction because if you are not using redux and you're about to think at another pattern, well, that will be probably an antipattern. Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html